# Placing directive logic inside controller rather than link

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

I have a general question. I've recently seen plenty of examples of people putting all their directive logic in a directive controller (and using it with controllerAs) instead of using link. I do see certain benefits in that:

1. The directive logic can be easily unit-tested.
2. You are seamlessly obligated to use the "dot notation" in your view model, thus prevent unexpected behavior.

As for the disadvantages - once the logic is inside the controller, it is exposed to other directives, as if encouraging developers of other directives to access those variables/methods, even if they are not meant to be accessed from outside.
I am interested in getting your take on this? How do you organize your code inside the directive.

Thanks

Comment: This is an interesting question. It seems like a lot of overlap between link and directice-controller. Seems like in the future it will just be an annotated class -- which is essentially the same as a ControllerAs constructor function. Can you link to some of these examples? Are they from style guides?

Comment: http://teropa.info/blog/2014/10/24/how-ive-improved-my-angular-apps-by-banning-ng-controller.html
@Martin above is one of them. Ill try find others that I've read

Answer (score 0):

I am using Angular for about 4 months so I cannot
Say that I have too much experience. However in my
Personal experience I used the controller only for logic
That needs to be shared or executed before the link
Function. I guess you can hide some logic from your controller by using the module pattern and only exposing the logic that is really necessary. In my defense I haven't wrote really complicated controllers but this is the way I would go. (Sorry for my bad writing I am responding from my phone)